# Laravel 8 fresh installation with livewire npm install && npm run dev error

Tags: laravel

When installing fresh Laravel 8.1 with livewire when in CLI i run npm run dev i got this i m new so please help me out?

```
> mix

[webpack-cli] /var/www/html/Am2/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Mix.js:18
static _primary = null;
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (/var/www/html/Am2/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:240:18)
at Module._compile (/var/www/html/Am2/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:184:36)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (/var/www/html/Am2/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
at module.exports (/var/www/html/Am2/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:2:17)
```

**Error**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Need to update node version.**

> **Ubuntu (Linux)**

Run this command to update node

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

after this close current terminal and open new one and run this command in **PROJECT DIR**

```
sudo npm install 
npm run dev
```

Comment: Thank you @Parth this solution worked like a charm. Upvoted

Answer (score 9):

Just try to upgrade your current node version

[Current stable](https://nodejs.org/dist/v15.5.1/node-v15.5.1.pkg) 15.5.1

you can upgrade it using brew in Mac-OS  case:

```
brew install nvm
nvm install 15
nvm use 15
```

Comment: I have node 15.12 but still the same error? Have you any idea what could be the problem?