# npm run dev not working after laravel/ui installation in laravel 8 app

Tags: php, laravel, npm, laravel-8, npm-run

I have installed laravel/ui in my laravel 8 app using

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui:auth
php artisan ui bootstrap
```

Later I did

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

**npm install** command works fine but while running **npm run dev**,

It generates following error

```
> @ dev /home/shreyas/Documents/laravel-projects/laracast-course/register-user
> npm run development


> @ development /home/shreyas/Documents/laravel-projects/laracast-course/register-user
> mix

[webpack-cli] /home/shreyas/Documents/laravel-projects/laracast-course/register-user/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Mix.js:18
    static _primary = null;
                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
    at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (/home/shreyas/Documents/laravel-projects/laracast-course/register-user/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:240:18)
    at Module._compile (/home/shreyas/Documents/laravel-projects/laracast-course/register-user/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:184:36)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (/home/shreyas/Documents/laravel-projects/laracast-course/register-user/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at module.exports (/home/shreyas/Documents/laravel-projects/laracast-course/register-user/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:2:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/shreyas/.npm/_logs/2021-01-12T09_20_27_344Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/shreyas/.npm/_logs/2021-01-12T09_20_27_447Z-debug.log
```

Due to this error, app did not compiled anything to render from public folder of laravel. I am using

6.14.4 (npm -v)

v10.19.0 (node -v)

**I tried to reinstall npm and node. But after reinstalling, error is still there**

webpack.mix.js file

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sourceMaps();
```

Comment: can you show your `webpack.mix.js` file

Comment: check  this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65653570/laravel-8-fresh-installation-with-livewire-npm-install-npm-run-dev-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to update nodejs. *(Currently on v14.15.4)*

Use `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` and confirm you're up to date with `nodejs -v`; then try again.

Comment: I've nvm installed and current nodejs is `v18.16.0` but still dose not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

**I could not find out what exactly is the problem but I solved it in this way.**

before installing Laravel ui my devDependencies were like this

```
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19",
    "cross-env": "^7.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
}
```

then I installed Laravel UI and used bootstrap auth. After installing my devDependencies changed to this and I was not able to run "npm run dev". It showed an error like this,

```
[webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--hide-modules'
[webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options
```

Then I updated all of my npm packages using "npm update" and also updated the npm script for running Laravel mix. Now my package.json file looks like this and **it works.**

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "cross-env": "^7.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.43",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.11",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
}
}
```