# How to resolve error when I run command npm run dev

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8; my error is the following.

> ```
> [webpack-cli] D:\appdownloads\www\laravel_8\chaythu1\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\Mix.js:18
>     static _primary = null;
>                     ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
>     at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
>     at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (D:\appdownloads\www\laravel_8\chaythu1\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:240:18)
>     at Module._compile (D:\appdownloads\www\laravel_8\chaythu1\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:184:36)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
>     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
>     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
>     at require (D:\appdownloads\www\laravel_8\chaythu1\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
>     at module.exports (D:\appdownloads\www\laravel_8\chaythu1\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js:2:17)
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 2
> npm ERR! @ development: `mix`
> npm ERR! Exit status 2
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hieu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-14T02_56_14_187Z-debug.log
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 2
> npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
> npm ERR! Exit status 2
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hieu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-14T02_56_14_261Z-debug.log
> ```

Comment: Have you taken a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65653570/laravel-8-fresh-installation-with-livewire-npm-install-npm-run-dev-error?

Answer (score 1):

First, check your node version using `node -v`. I guess your current node version isn't the latest version. So upgrade your node and then use `npm install` and `npm run dev` will solve your problem.

You are using windows so if you have no idea about how to upgrade let's check [How to upgrade node.js on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699215/how-to-upgrade-node-js-on-windows)